# Extracting data from natural language text

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have a set of text newspaper ads, I'd like to extract information like the item being sold and its price. These ads don't follow any structured format. I have access to many thousands of these ads.

Where should I start on this project? Is there some library that would help out?

Thanks

Comment: It depends  a lot on "items". Prices will be easy to capture will regex or rules as other users have answered. For items, it depends on how structured (or not) items are. Can you provide a few examples ?

Comment: Not structured, suppose I'm looking at bike ads and I want to extract the name of the bike. So the ad would be like "Hi, finally selling my old bike, it's a GT Aggressor 3.0 and would like $300." Right now, I'm leaning towards a rule-based approach, so I would encode the names of popular bikes and search for strings that are close to them. But anything more sophisticated would be nice to hear about!

Answer (score 3):

The most simple approach seems to use **rules** and **dictionaries**. For example, you can parse prices with simple regexes and use large dictionary of items to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your coding experience, and depending on how the text files are formatted, one way would be to import them into Excel and use the Text to Columns function to somehow split the advert's fields into separate cells.

For example if you had **Name: Black car** and **Price: $1000.00** then Excel can easily split them using the Text to Columns function set to split on the colon.

Perhaps explain in more detail how the text files are formatted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to this concept, you may try look following [videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc3MI_aeHsw) of [IBM Big Insight Text Analytics](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/bigins/v1r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.doc/doc/r0057884.html).Their project is extracting price information about IBM shares, similar to your project. 
They start with this project and with a series of videos almost complete it. 
Along the way , they teach more about regex.

Note that this videos may help you understand workflow of this type of project. If you are proficient in any programming language with good regex support, perl,ruby, python, groovy ... You may repeat their experiment easily.

Also I never used this product, but watched all this videos with hope of learning more about text mining. 
I repeat you may do all of this without this product but less easily of course.